# Apple pay return null using Payment Request Button stripe.js

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am integrating the Payment Request button in Reactjs but it returns null in IOS devices and working on Android and Desktop Chrome. I registered ngrok domain in stripe dashboard and added a card in the safari browser for MacBook and in wallet for iPhone but it still throws the same error. Let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Apple Pay can be tricky get set up with. Have you followed the prerequisite guidelines [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?html-or-react=html#verifying-your-domain-with-apple-pay)? I'd recommend writing in to [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact).